# Bootstrap col-xs-offset-0 doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code. I want to resize my image, but it doesn't work with col-xs-offset-0. (I want to center it)

What could be the problem here? I want my image to get big with col-xs and centered.

I don't want to use col-xs-4 since it'll make my image too small. I can't col-xs-5 because then I can't use offset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-0">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.turkcealtyazi.org/images/poster/0903747.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rx4ptj2k/

Comment: Off-topic: Since Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first (with an upward cascade), it's easier to decipher your column declaration classes if they're also mobile-first (listed smallest to largest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An offset of zero would only be appropriate if you had a width of 12. As it's 6 columns wide, you'd divide the remainder of the 12 in half for a result of 3.

Use `col-xs-offset-3` instead of `col-xs-offset-0`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rx4ptj2k/7/)**